# Proper top level navigations in android fragments like in Google Play

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an Activity with navigation drawer and a default fragment set in to Activity when application starts.

I have 4 top level navigation in my navigation drawer

1. Fragment 1
2. Fragment 2
3. Fragment 3
4. Fragment 4

and switching the fragments inside the activity on click on each each navigation. I want implement the fragment navigation in such manner that from each top level navigation fragment, if user clicks back button it should first come to Main or default fragment and from there app should exit same like in Google Play. I call it master fragment.

eg:

Default(master) Fragment > Fragment 1

Fragment > Fragment 2

Fragment 2 -- Back pressed > Deafult fragment and like so.

**What I have tried so far :**

I have tried adding fragment in backstack but it doesn't help it takes me all fragment in stack.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, selectedFragment)
            .addToBackStack("naviagtion_stack")
            .commit();
```

My each top fragments also have child fragments in stack so stack count also did not help me.

I don't want to remove and add my default fragment because as it fetches some data from network so recreation will make the network call again which i don't want .

I want exactly what Google Play does. I just want to know the logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your master fragment to backstack and remember the tag: `fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.main_layout, masterFragment)
                .addToBackStack(INITIAL_STATE)
                .commit();`

Click on the navigation elements should do following before adding a corresponding fragment: `fragmentManager.popBackStack(INITIAL_STATE, 0);`
This call removes from backstack everything but your master fragment.

All fragment transactions (including navigation fragments) should generally do the same thing, for example:
`fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.main_layout, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();`

Comment: I did what you mentioned and thing seems working fine but only small issue I am facing. i need to click twice on my main fragment to get exit from app because the default or main fragment is also in stack. let me know how to get rid of this.

Comment: override onBackPressed() in your Activity and perform finish() if (fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() == 1)

Comment: I did the same but is there any other way to clear the stack if count is 2 so after 2 if someone presses back there is nothing encountered in stack and it comes to 0 directly and `super.onBackPressed` close the app ?

Comment: you can use [POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html#POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE), but you'll probably get blank screen on 0 stack count

Comment: ya same thing is happening, I am getting blank if I click on main fragment and than one more back press if exiting the app.